# Translation(s) of '지지직' meaning a sound?

Tags: vocabulary

I saw '지지직' in a movie subtitle, and inferred its meaning as something like a 'crackle'.

However, another example I [found online](http://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?sLn=en&isOnlyViewEE=N&query=%EC%A7%80%EC%A7%80%EC%A7%81) was

> 지지직거리나요? Do you hear that?

And other examples suggest it could mean 'noise' in general, whilst a youtube hit of a sound effect I found seemed to be more a 'hiss' than a crackle.

What is the range of translations of '지지직'?

Comment: [An electrical noise.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MlaZ19V5n8) _Bzzzt_ without the initial `B` (pop) sound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

지지직거리다 means 액체가 졸아붙으면서 끓는 소리가 자꾸 나다.
[link](http://m.krdic.naver.com/entry/35817801/%EC%A7%80%EC%A7%80%EC%A7%81%EA%B1%B0%EB%A6%AC%EB%8B%A4/?format=HTML&isMobile=true)
in official Korean. but Koreans use it when electronic devices's sound or screen goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

"지지직" means white noise [like this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Image:White-noise-sound-20sec-mono-44100Hz.ogg) (It's too noisy, so you should turn down the volume).

You can use "지지직" for this kind of noise.